# CSS: menu bar shifted to right in Safari

Tags: css, safari

For some reason, my menu bar is shifted to right in Safari:

http://www.danydiop.com/danydiop/

In Firefox it is correct. What should I change in the css code ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
#header-blocks {
  position: absolute;
}
```

instead of `position: fixed`.

---

You should, however, seriously consider cutting down on the number and complexity of the stylesheets you're using.

Comment: great thanks. That's Drupal CMS, I will compact them when website will be ready.